# How to display a list of all folds?

Tags: command-line, folding, command

How can I show a list of all folds?

e.g., maybe a list something like:

```
1-3
12-18
13-16
```

where `<start-line>-<end-line>` are the starting and ending lines of the fold.

Is there a command-line command that will do this?  Or a script that could do it?

I know about `:set foldcolumn=12` but I'd like a list rather than visually looking through the file.

Comment: Ugh. vimscript support for folds sucks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish something reasonable with the following code:

```
function CollectFolds() abort
  if !exists('s:folds')
    let s:folds = []
  endif
  const line = line('.')
  const end = foldclosedend(line)
  if !exists('s:prev_end') " first one
    let s:prev_end = end
    call add(s:folds, [line, end])
  elseif end isnot# s:prev_end " new fold
    call add(s:folds, [line, end])
    let s:prev_end = end
  endif
endfunction

command PrintFolds execute 'folddoclosed call CollectFolds()' | echo s:folds | unlet s:folds s:prev_end
```

You can drop it in `~/.vim/plugin/printfolds.vim` (though it should really have an `if exists('g:loaded_printfolds')` guard for that).

Change `echo s:folds` if you want to touch up the formatting.

---

The idea is to maintain a running state of the end of the current fold; when we start a new fold (the end changes), we add the fold start and end to the list of folds.

---

This approach only counts closed folds, so it skips nested folds and such. See previous edits for other versions. (If you know what `foldmethod` is, or use `foldmarker` or some other smarter technique, you might do better.)

---

It might be possible to get more robust by tweaking [my fold-detection code from AutoOrigami](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-auto-origami/blob/eb8c08d12fa7889b53d17072d477f013fb8249a1/autoload/auto_origami.vim#L37). Heck, at that point, you migth be better off looping through the file and tracking previous `foldlevel()` and such. As filbranden points out below, this comes with its own detection problems; adjacent lines with the same fold level but that belong to different folds need to be distinguished, probably based on `foldclosedend` (which limits you to closed folds again; I mocked this up, and it almost works, but not quite).

Comment: *"looping through the file and tracking previous `foldlevel()`"* This was my first thought, but it fails if you have a line closing a fold level 2 followed by another that opens a new fold level 2. Both lines will be at the same fold level, but they're separate folds.

Comment: Ah, good thought @filbranden